# How to run a macro on some but not all sheets in a workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that contains worksheets for each industry group in the S&P 500 and wrote the macro below to update all the stock information on them when I press a command button on the first worksheet. The macro works perfectly, but when I go to add additional sheets that I do not want to update with this macro it stops working. I tried using the "If Not" statements below, but it did not seem to work.

```
Sub Get_Stock_Quotes_from_Yahoo_Finance_API()

'Run the API for every sheet in the workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Look to see what the sheet is named and run the macro if it is not what is below
    If Not Sht.Name = "Cover" _
    And Not Sht.Name = "Select Industry" Then

    Sht.Activate

        ' Dim varibales and set range
        Dim head As Range
        Set head = Worksheet.Range("A2")

        'dim variables
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim Symbols As String: Symbols = ""
        Dim SpecialTags As String: SpecialTags = ""
        Dim Yahoo_Finance_URL As String: Yahoo_Finance_URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim cell As Range

        ' Get the Stock Symbols
        Set rng = Range(head.Offset(1, 0), head.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
        For Each cell In rng ' Starting from a cell below the head cell till the last filled cell
            Symbols = Symbols & cell.Value & "+"
        Next cell
        Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1) ' Remove the last '+'

        ' Get the Special Tags
        Set rng = Range(head.Offset(0, 1), head.Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight))
        For Each cell In rng ' Starting from a cell to the right of the head cell till the last filled cell
            SpecialTags = SpecialTags & cell.Value
        Next

        ' Put the desciption/name of each tag in the cell above it
        Dim SpecialTagsArr() As String: Dim TagNamesArr() As String
        Call Get_Special_Tags(SpecialTagsArr, TagNamesArr)
        For Each cell In rng
            cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = FindTagName(cell.Value, SpecialTagsArr, TagNamesArr)
        Next


        Yahoo_Finance_URL = Yahoo_Finance_URL & Symbols & "&f=" & SpecialTags

        Call Print_CSV(Yahoo_Finance_URL, head)

Next Sht
'At the end of the program say it has all been updated
MsgBox ("All Data Updated")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 If Not Sht.Name = "Cover" _
    And Not Sht.Name = "Select Industry" Then
```

To

```
If Sht.Name <> "Cover" And Sht.Name <> "Select Industry" Then
```

Don't forget your `End If` before `Next Sht`

Comment: Thanks for the help I changed it to that and it still isn't working I think there might be a problem with where my end if is. This is what the code looks like now I put the end if at the end of the code before the next sht.

Comment: @KevinZell - when you say *it still isn't working* what is not working? Also, make sure you see my edited `And` for `Or`.

Comment: the "And" Fixed it and now its working thank you for your help

Comment: glad it worked @KevinZell - please check as "answered" and also delete your answer so the problem and solution remain clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Refering to Kevin's second code - now the exclusion logic is flawed. I suggest the following:

```
Function IsIn(element, arr) As Boolean
    IsIn = False
    For Each x In arr
        If element = x Then
            IsIn = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next x
End Function


Sub Get_Stock_Quotes_from_Yahoo_Finance_API()
    Dim skippedSheets()
    skippedSheets = Array("Cover,Select Industry,bla bla")

    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not IsIn(Sh.Name, skippedSheets) Then
            ' ... process Sh

        End If
    Next Sh
End Sub
```

Now you have all sheet names which are to be excluded in one place (the array assignment) and the inner code block will only be executed if the current sheet name is not element of that array.

Second source of error: you already started qualifying the ranges (like in `Set head = Sht.Range("A2")`). Do the same in 2 other places, with
`Set rng = Sht.Range(head.Offset(1, 0), head.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))`
and
`Set rng = Sht.Range(head.Offset(0, 1), head.Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight))`

Last, you don't have to `activate` a sheet. You work with the `Sht` object and qualified ranges.
`Dim I as Integer` is unused.